# PHP MySQL array multidimensional

Tags: php, array, mysqli, array-multidimensional, array-push

Estou com um pouco de dificuldade em atribuir um index para englobar os itens marcados na figura abaixo num array multidimensional que estou montando com as consultas do banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso pegar de outra tabela os posts de cada usuário e somar no array "hosters" junto dos outros dados vindos da primeira consulta.

Fazendo a consulta numa query única produz vários registros de acordo com o número de posts de cada "hoster", então não seria viável.

Estou fazendo um `array_push` para "somar" no mesmo array, porém, precisa de um index ali onde está marcado na imagem pra poder percorrer os posts no frontend.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if (isset($data->city)) {

    $city = $data->city;
    $retorno = array();

    $sql = "SELECT m.userId, m.username, m.lastname, m.city, m.state, s.id FROM members m, signup s 
    WHERE city = ? AND m.userId = s.id AND s.hostOption = 'true' ";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($mID, $username, $lastname, $city, $state, $sID);

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            $result = array(
                "id" => $mID,
                "name" => $username,
                "lastname" => $lastname,
                "city" => $city,
                "state" => $state,
            );

            $selectImages = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tours WHERE user_id = '" . $sID . "' ");
            while ($row = $selectImages->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

                $tours = array("title" => $row['title']);
                array_push($result, $tours);
            }
            $retorno[] = $result;
        }

        $hosters["hosters"] = $retorno;
    }
    $return = json_encode($hosters);
    echo $return;
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Eu tentei colocar `$tours["tour"] = array("title" => $row['title']);` mas ele joga o index "pra dentro" hehe. Acredito ser algo simples pra quem tem mais prática com arrays. Grato desde já!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo fazer dessa forma:

```
$tour = array();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        $result = array(
            "id" => $mID,
            "name" => $username,
            "lastname" => $lastname,
            "city" => $city,
            "state" => $state,
            "tour" => $tour
        );

        $selectImages = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tours WHERE user_id = '" . $sID . "' ");
        while ($row = $selectImages->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

            $tours = array("title" => $row['title'], "description" => $row['description']);
            array_push($result["tour"], $tours);
        }
        $retorno[] = $result;
    }

    $hosters["hosters"] = $retorno;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]